# PHP Laravel complex query with multiple options

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, laravel, eloquent

I have a search form with has 4 fields:

1. Title
2. Genre -> (Seperate query to get find genres)
3. Rating
4. Order by -> (Included in all query's)

I am trying to optimise the search function as it is around 300 lines long. What I have done is written out all possible combinations - what should be included in the query.

```
if ( empty($title) && $genre === 'All' && $rating === '0') {}
if (!empty($title) && $genre === 'All' && $rating === '0') {}
```

There is 8 possible combinations and I don't know how to optimize this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a very nice solution which would also make adding additional criteria a snap.

I don't know what your class name is, so I am assuming you have a table of books and a model Book.

So here is what seems to be working for me on a quick test table I setup.

```
$books = new Book;

if(!empty($title))
    $books = $books->where('title','=',$title);

if(!empty($genre))
    $books = $books->where('genre','=',$genre);

if(!empty($rating))
    $books = $books->where('rating','=',$rating);

$books = $books->get();
```